# Paypal In-Context Checkout Remove Review, Billing Required Text

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, express-checkout

I have integrated paypal in-context checkout in a python flask project using python [Paypal Python SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK).

User will give donation via paypal or credit card. So I have disabled the shipping option by creating a *WEB EXPERIENCE* Profile with `no-shipping=1`.

Now Paypal In Context Popup after login, Looks Like Below, 
[image]

This two lines seems confusing to me,

- You'll be able to review your order before you complete your purchase.
- The merchant requires your billing address to complete the payment.

I have disabled shipping, and accepting donation, so I don't need any billing or order review.

Is it possible to remove those lines from the UI ?

Answer (score 0):

UI cannot be removed or edited. But 'NOSHIPPING=1' just means that no shipping address is required from your customer end.

Comment: `The merchant requires your billing address to complete the payment.` I can  complete the payment without the billing address bing entered as `no-shipping` turned on.